# The system administrator has set policies to prevent this installation

Tags: group-policy

I have set up a domain and added a workstation to it.  I'm trying to install VMware server and it says, "The system administrator has set policies to prevent this installation".  I tried running the setup as Administrator on the local machine, but this didn't work.

I think I need to all my username to install software using something like GPO or something of sort.  I don't know how to even begin this process.  Any tutorials or instructions? Is this really what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this problem is due to the size of the MSI of VMware server.

I'd recommend following this solution

http://communities.vmware.com/message/1122261;jsessionid=533FF552AAFC0F3162338C9EE1957331

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have some kind of software restriction policy either on the domain or in the local computer's security policy.

To check the domain policy, you may want to run rsop.exe at a command prompt on the client PC to see what is being controlled by a GPO and which GPO is the one in question. Look in the software restriction policy node of GPO (shown in the link to follow...). From there you can check your domain policies and make the [appropriate changes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324036).

If it's a local policy (like for instance some weird MLGPO that someone set up if you have Vista or 7) I'd just browse to the software restriction policy node using run >> gpedit.msc and see for yourself. Computer Settings >> Windows Settings >> Security Settings >> Software Restriction Policies.

Of course, this is assuming that you're the SysAdmin and are allowed to do these things. =)

Comment: It says windows can not find rsop.exe.

I don't think it's local as it is my own machine and I am the admin and I don't think I would have locked it down in such a way.

I am the admin.

Thanks.

Comment: @Noah Clark: It's rsop.msc not rsop.exe (xp/vista/7)

Comment: I get this:

"The RSoP Snap-in was unable to generate data due to the computers permissions"

I click OK... and then the Resultant Set of Policy opens.

Does this help at all?

Thanks Zypher for the clarification!

Comment: Okay, new tactic. Try using gpresult.exe at a command line. You'll have to check out the paramters based on your requirements, but I think you'll want to use /USER [yourusername] and maybe even /H <filename> to export it as HTML. /Z could be useful to see if the setting was applied in multiple places.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/m44f57fb7 is what I get.  I think Daniel is on to something, but I can't do that until I get the proper permissions.  The gpresult.exe doesn't show me anything that looks out of place.

Comment: Noah, you have to run gpresult in an elevated command prompt to see the "Computer Settings" portion of GPResult. Although I think you're right that Daniel's post has nailed it. Also, run gpresult with the /v flag.

Comment: Nonapeptide, thanks for sticking with me on this.  My understanding is that there is no elevated command prompt in windows XP, so I logged in as administrator and here is what I got with the v flag: http://pastebin.com/m7e938f26

Comment: Oops. for some reason I thought you were on XP. =) Have you checked into the VMWare forum thread to see if that's the issue?

Comment: I am on windows XP. Why did you think I'm not?

Comment: Let me rephrase my last comment. It should have read "Oops. for some reason I thought you were **not** on XP." I made a poor assumption that you were on Vista or 7 and furthering the failure I then typed out a poorly worded comment. I wonder if that qualifies for an EPIC FAIL! =)

Comment: Perhaps, I don't really know what I'm looking for in the paste bin.  But everything seems make sense and not stick out.  Did you get a chance to look at it?

Comment: I'm still only seeing User Settings and not Computer Settings. I'm an AD novice so I'm not sure how to get exactly what Computer Settings GPOs are being applied to your machine. Have you looked into the VMWare forum thread yet?

Comment: Yeah.  I checked that out and that is the solution, but for whatever reason I can't follow the directions because my machine is locked down by AD and being in the domain.  I'll keep working on this issue.  Thanks for the help!